# Unable to access some tags on a site for Web-Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to web scrape Citibike tripdata. Since there are multiple files I want to download, I thought better to automate this with python by accessing desired links and then using other methods to download them

here is my code:

```
url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/index.html'
html_source = requests.get(url).text 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html.parser")
soup.prettify() 

# I'm successful until I add '.find_all('tr')' at the end
citibikedata = soup.find('tbody', id = "tbody-content").find_all('tr') 
print(citibikedata)
```

[image: HTML Page Screenshot Attached]

When I try to print, I get an empty `list`. If I do length (`len`), I get 0.
However, if I remove the `find_all()`, I get results for just the `tbody-content`.

I suspect that for some reason I'm not able to access the `tr` tag. Meanwhile, there's another layer of tag, 'td', that I have to access in order for me to fetch the data I'm actually looking for, which are the `href` and text in the `a` tag.

Please what am I missing, I will appreciate your help. Many thanks in advance

I couldn't find online resources where tags without classes were accessed, which is my suspicion for the issue. Perhaps, it not.

Comment: All those `tr` elements are loaded dynamically. They're not present in the source HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue here, data is as mentioned loaded dynamically, so you could fetch it from the source it comes from.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata will provide a XML file that contains your data, simply iterate its items and pick your urls.

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/'
links = [
         base_url+key.text
         for key in BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url).text).select('Key')
        ]
links
```

###### Output

```
['https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201306-citibike-tripdata.zip',
 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201307-201402-citibike-tripdata.zip',
 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201307-citibike-tripdata.zip',
 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201308-citibike-tripdata.zip',
 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201309-citibike-tripdata.zip',
 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201310-citibike-tripdata.zip',...]
```

---

Based on your comment you could use `dict` or a `list` of `dicts`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/'

data = []
         
for e in BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url).text).select('Contents'):
        data.append({
                'url':base_url+e.key.text,
                'date': e.lastmodified.text
        })
data
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help @HedgeHog.
I also need the date. I can either use the 'LastModified' tag or strip the Key for year/mm (e.g 201306), either of these is fine by me.

My question is how do I achieve either of them and the date to accompany the link as same record, while there's space between each thereafter records?

Comment: It deviates somewhat from the OP and should therefore rather be posed as a new question with precisely this focus. But I have expanded my answer, feel free to have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You need some help from [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) :

```
#pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
​
url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/index.html"
​
with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    tag = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser").find_all("a")
    links = [link.get("href") for link in tag if link.get("href")]
​
```

Output :

```
#links

['https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201306-citibike-tripdata.zip',
 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201307-201402-citibike-tripdata.zip',
 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201307-citibike-tripdata.zip',
 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201308-citibike-tripdata.zip',
 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201309-citibike-tripdata.zip',
 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201310-citibike-tripdata.zip',
 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201311-citibike-tripdata.zip',
 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201312-citibike-tripdata.zip',
 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201401-citibike-tripdata.zip',
 ...
```

Comment: This answer worked, and I wish I could mark it too, but I can only mark one.
I chose the answer from @HedgeHog for two reasons:

1. It is with the fewest lines of code
2. I'm familiar with BeautifulSoup as opposed to Selenium, which is used here.

Advantage of this response:
1. Selenium is better for Dynamic site scrapping. Something I found out in this process and thus will include in my learning plan.

Many thanks Timeless

Comment: Many roads lead to rom - your explanation makes it easy to understand why you chose yours, and perhaps you will choose the other one at a different project. To express your sportsmanship, take a minute and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up, this will also enable you to honour any / other helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, if you check the:

```
citibikedata = soup.find('tbody', id = "tbody-content")
print(citibikedata)
>> <tbody id="tbody-content">
   </tbody>
```

Although you are able to get the `tbody` tag, it does not contain any data inside and you get an empty list when you further try to find the `tr` tags in it.

But you can achieve your goal using **Selenium**.

Here is how you can do it:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/index.html'
driver = Chrome()
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tbody#tbody-content')))
html_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html.parser")

citibikedata = soup.find('tbody', id="tbody-content").find_all('tr')
print(citibikedata)
```

citibikedata:

```
[<tr>
<td><i class="icon-file i-file-or-folder" style="margin-left:calc((1 * 16px) + 4px);"></i>
<a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/201306-citibike-tripdata.zip">201306-citibike-tripdata.zip</a>
</td>
<td>Apr 30th 2018, 08:18:55 pm</td>
<td>16.79 MB</td>
<td>ZIP file</td>
</tr>, 
...
...
<tr>
<td><i class="icon-file i-file-or-folder" style="margin-left:calc((1 * 16px) + 4px);"></i>
<a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/index.html">index.html</a>
</td>
<td>Jan 19th 2017, 05:23:41 am</td>
<td>6 KB</td>
<td>HTML file</td>
</tr>
]
```